# Removed an outlet attached to a lighting circuit, now the room sockets have lost power

Tags: electrical

My wife has finished cooking so I reattached the socket and the circuit is now working.

So my question becomes - how can I remove this socket and the wire without breaking the circuit?

---

I recently had a load bearing wall removed from my property and the leftover electrical work has been dangling between two rooms.

It's a triple gang light switch with a socket attached to the end. Two of the three lights are 3-way switches although all three switches are using 14/3 cable.

There are two sockets coming up from the floor that are on a different circuit if the extra wire is confusing. These are not connected to the circuit in question.

I removed the socket from the bottom of this 3 gang box. It was connected by a 14/2 cable spliced with neutrals and hots in the box.

All the lights are still working but I've lost power to the electrical sockets and my outdoor light.

I'm puzzled because I wouldn't have thought that removing the socket would have impacted the circuit. Is it this or is it something else?

Troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- Cycled every breaker into a fully off and then on position

[image: pre-demo wall]

[image].

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many wires were attached to the receptacle you removed?

Comment: It's 14/2 with an earth.

Comment: Only one 14/2 though?

Comment: Yeah just 1 wire from the gang box to the socket.

Comment: I've added pictures of the socket/wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A receptacle with a single cable running to it will have no effect on the rest of the circuit (unless you short the white to black and trip the breaker).

I would suggest you wiggled the wires going to the switches (they look to be back stabbed). Backstabbed wiring is by far the largest failure cause in modern wiring.

If you search you may find answers on this site that tell you to check the devices and when you turn the power back on and it works the stab started working because of the wire wiggle. Since this in new use the screw terminals not backstabs or this will end up being a common issue until the stab / wire is burned off from arcing and you find the root cause.

Comment: I switched from wire nuts to lever nuts and the lights now function without the socket. Thank you sir.